# Have the clock in a Zabbix screen show host time

Tags: time, screen, monitoring, clock, zabbix

In Zabbix 3.2, I am setting up a screen for a new server, and want to configure a clock that shows the local time from the monitored host.

This is how I configured the screen element:

[image: Zabbix screen confiure clock]

I have checked in Latest Data that the Host localtime is being received (it is).

However, when I save this screen configuration, the display just says, "No data":

[image: CZabbix clock display - No data]

How do you display the time on the monitored host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this screen element to work, you have to use `system.localtime[local]` item (which returns a string in a certain format, see [item documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent)) instead of the default `system.localtime` (which returns an integer timestamp).

The `system.localtime[local]` item returns a string like the following:

```
2016-12-07,09:36:59.688,+02:00
```

It allows the frontend to nicely display the time zone:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was it.